# Interpret user entered dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, input, format, interpreter

I was looking for a convenient method to take a date entered by a user and do the following:

1) Determine if the Date entered is valid, and if it is valid, return an object with:

2) A JavaScript Date object

3) The date formatted in mySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD)

4) The date formatted in typical format (MM-DD-YYYY)

In the end I wrote my own function that uses Regex and can handle an input of YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY/MM/DD, MM-DD-YY, MM/DD/YY, MM-DD-YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY.

The reason that the function returns mySQL format and regular format in the object is simply for convenience. My web app needs the typical format to display in the field and the mysQL format to send to the server when saving data.

The code is shown below in my answer. I'm sure there are ways to optimize the code, but I wrote it in parts for the ease of reading. And even if it was set to run every time a user entered data in a date field, it wouldn't bog anything down. Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is much better.

The code and an example can be seen here on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukewarm74/3MWyR/13/).

```
function interpretDate(stringDate){
    var mysqlF = "(\\d{4})[-/](\\d{1,2})[-/](\\d{1,2})";
    var dispF = "(\\d{1,2})[-/](\\d{1,2})[-/]((?:\\d{4})|(?:\\d{2}))";
    var dispNoYearF = "(\\d{1,2})[-/](\\d{1,2})";
    var dateFormats = "(^"+mysqlF+"$)|(^"+dispF+"$)|(^"+dispNoYearF+"$)";

    //Let's try to extract the data
    data = stringDate.match(dateFormats);
    var month = -1;
    var day = -1;
    var year = -1;

    //Check to see if the verification failed
    if (data == undefined){
        //Invalid date
        return {valid: false, date: null, mysqlDate:null, displayDate: ""};
    }

    //Extract the data based on the entry type
    if (data[1] != undefined){//YYYY-MM-DD
        month = parseInt(data[3]);
        day = parseInt(data[4]);
        year = parseInt(data[2]);
    }else if (data[5] != undefined){//MM-DD-YYYY or MM-DD-YY
        month = parseInt(data[6]);
        day = parseInt(data[7]);
        year = parseInt(data[8]);
        if (year < 100){
            var yearString = new String(new Date().getFullYear());
            year = parseInt(yearString.substr(0,2) + year);
        }
    }else if (data[9] != undefined){//MM-DD
        month = parseInt(data[10]);
        day = parseInt(data[11]);
        year = parseInt(new Date().getFullYear());
    }

    //If we are here, we have three numbers, let's see if they make a real date
    var extractedDate = new Date(year, month-1, day);
    if (extractedDate.getFullYear() != year || extractedDate.getDate() != day || extractedDate.getMonth() != (month-1)){
        return {valid: false, date: null, mysqlDate:null, displayDate: ""};
    }

    //We have a valid date, let's add front zeros
    var monthFixed = month;
    if (monthFixed < 10) monthFixed = "0"+monthFixed;
    var dayFixed = day;
    if (dayFixed < 10) dayFixed = "0"+dayFixed;

    //We are done
    return {valid: true, date: extractedDate, mysqlDate:year+"-"+monthFixed+"-"+dayFixed, displayDate: month+"/"+day+"/"+year};
}
```